# Fourier series of a continuous function converging to non-value of function?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I know of examples of periodic continuous functions whose Fourier series diverge on sets of measure zero. Is it possible for a Fourier series of a periodic continuous function to converge to something other than the function value, at some point?  If so, can someone provide an example or reference?

Answer (score 9):

1. If a series converges to a limit $L$, its Cesaro averages converge to the same limit $L$.
2. The Cesaro averages of a Fourier series are given by convolution with the Fejer kernel, and it is known that convolving an element of $C({\bf T})$ with the Fejer kernel always gives a sequence of trigonometric polynomials converging uniformly to the given function.

So I think the answer to your question is negative: if $f$ is continuous, and if the partial sums of $\sum_{n\in{\bf Z}} \hat{f}(n)e^{2\pi int}$ converge to some $L$, then $L=f(t)$.

Comment: Yes, and the result itself is due to Fejér: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r%27s_theorem

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  What about the following generalization of this question for discontinuous functions:  if the Fourier series converges to L at some point, does L have to be within the oscillation interval of the function at that point?

Comment: And, in particular, if there is a jump discontinuity at t, does L have to be the center point of the oscillation interval?

Comment: @GHfromMO Yes, I should have stated that point number 2 is Fejer's theorem. Point number 1 would have been known to him and well before him

Comment: @ZbigniewFiedorowicz For your extended question: precisely what assumptions do you put on this discontinuous function? For instance, I don't see how to interpret your question for $L^p({\bf T})$ functions since they can be changed arbitrarily on sets of measure zero

Comment: @ZbigniewFiedorowicz The Wikipedia page for Fejer's theorem has some results for what can be said at points of discontinuity if the left and right limits exist

Comment: @Yemon Choi  I guess I am thinking of a function which is continuous except for a finite set of discontinuities within a periodicity interval.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57117/discussion-between-zbigniew-fiedorowicz-and-yemon-choi).